# Symfony Serializer - array to object conversion - naming strategy for each field

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I'm getting array like this from external API endpoint e.g Person API, but array keys names are in other language and with underscores - it is unacceptable by my code standards to use these names. Project is running by Symfony 4.x and PHP 7.1

```
[
    'first_name_in_other_language' => 'value',
    'last_name_in_other_language' => 'value',
    ...more fields
]
```

but i want to convert it to class entry with valid fields names e.g (note: `Person` is not doctrine entity - it's simple object to store data)

```
class Person {private $firstName; private $lastName; ...more fields}
```

Problem: I think i should make some kind of mapper array/object like

```
['first_name_in_other_language' => 'firstName']
```

but i can't find any examples of this approach related to `Symfony`
Maybe its because this problem is more related to hydrator than to serializer?

I find this chunk of code [there](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-06-21-zend-hydrator.html) from `zend hydrator` and it looks like it support feature that i need (`new MapNamingStrategy(['published' => 'isPublished'])`):

```
use Acme\Transaction;
use Zend\Hydrator\NamingStrategy\CompositeNamingStrategy;
use Zend\Hydrator\NamingStrategy\MapNamingStrategy;
use Zend\Hydrator\NamingStrategy\UnderscoreNamingStrategy;
use Zend\Hydrator\ObjectProperty as ObjectPropertyHydrator;

$underscoreNamingStrategy = new UnderscoreNamingStrategy();
$namingStrategy = new CompositeNamingStrategy([
    'isPublished' => new MapNamingStrategy(['published' => 'isPublished']),
    'publishedOn' => $underscoreNamingStrategy,
    'updatedOn'   => $underscoreNamingStrategy,
]);

$hydrator = new ObjectPropertyHydrator();
$hydrator->setNamingStrategy($namingStrategy);
$data = $hydrator->extract($transaction);
```

**Question**: It is possible to archive it with Symfony serializer or other Symfony components?

Comment: Hello grexlort ! Did you find a solution with Symfony Serializer for that ? I've seen we can use some annotation to do the mapping field by field but it doesn't work at i want. Thanks !

Comment: Finally I went with quick and dirty solution, something like in answer below, but I was not satisfied. If that problem occurs today, I would like to create two classes, one for deserialization purposes only (with ugly names) and second with desirable naming scheme. E.g `UglyApiResponse` and `NiceModel` and some code to create `NiceModel` from `UglyApiResponse`. Another possible solution is to implement `Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface` but still it don't solve the problem, rather it can be use to kinda hack solution in non-optimal way

Comment: Thanks to Symfony Serializer i was able to do what i wanted. For each Model i have a Formatter class used to transform data both way (It's possible to auto generate the formatter i think). The annotation @SerializedName is used for that. I just needed to configure the serializer with special class for reading metadata annotation on file !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example.

```
<?php
    
    namespace MyCompany\Bundle\SymfonyCustomerBundle\Formatter;
    
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\MetadataAwareNameConverter;
    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
    
    use Mycompany\Bundle\SymfonyCustomerBundle\Model\Contact;
    
    class ContactFormatter {
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            //TODO : Make it as a service injection for all formatter
            $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetaDataFactory(
                new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader())
            );
            $metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);
            $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
            $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter)];
    
            $this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        }
    
        public function formatToModel(array $rawData): Contact
        {
            return $this->serializer->denormalize($rawData, Contact::class);
        }
    
        public function formatToArray(Contact $contact): array
        {   
            return $this->serializer->normalize($contact);
        }
    }
```

And the Model using SerializedName annotation.

```
<?php

namespace Mycompany\Bundle\SymfonyCustomerBundle\Model;


use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

class Contact
{

    /**
     * @SerializedName("db_id_contact")
     */
    private int $idContact;

    /**
     * @SerializedName("db_nomContact")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private ?string $lastName = null;
    
    /**
     * @SerializedName("db_prenomContact")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private ?string $firstName = null;


    public function getIdContact(): int{
        return $this->idContact;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setIdContact($value){
        $this->idContact = $value;
    }

    public function setLastName(?string $value){
        $this->lastName = $value;
    }

    public function setFirstName(?string $value){
        $this->firstName = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about normalization? If you normalize `Contact` object to json then you probably got `db_nomContact` instead of `lastName`

Comment: Yes you are right. I think it's possible to not use annotation specially for Json with some extra configuration. I didn't need that at the moment but probably in the future so the question is good.

Answer (score -3):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you could add a constructor for your class like this:

```php
class Person{
         private $firstName;
         private $lastName;
         //other stuff
         function __construct($your_api_answer){
            $this->firstName = $your_api_answer["first_name_key_of_answer"];
            $this->lastName = $your_api_answer["last_name_key_of_answer"];
            //initialize other stuff
         }
    }

$person = new Person($your_api_answer);
```

Comment: my question is more related to symfony serializer or other symfony componets - i want to examine if its possbile to solve this problem by using existing symfony apis